# Is there any way to auto-close Safari's download window upon download completion?

Tags: safari

This is the only thing that bothers me with Safari, but it's a big deal. I've looked everywhere but can't seem to find any good suggestions. Is there any way to enable the Safari downloads window to automatically close when a download completes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the [Glims plugin](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27708/glims) for this, which has a host of other useful features, too.

Answer (score 2):

I use [SafariStand](https://web.archive.org/web/20150511130148/http://hetima.com/safari/stand-e.html) from Hetima.com (which also has many other useful features).

Answer (score 1):

I use <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> which doesn't have any other feature and doesn't do it automatically (but doesn't use any extra RAM) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[killDownloadsWindow](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/36297/killdownloadswindow):

> killDownloadsWindow is a lightweight utility that runs in the background and closes Safari's annoying download window when a download finishes. Simple, but effective